# HTML image troubles displaying image of a tree

Tags: html

This seems to be a problem that is asked here a lot, but after trying a few different solutions on this site, my problem has not yet been resolved. I am trying to display a picture of a tree, but the picture is not loading. My code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="Tree.jpg" alt="Tree">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Tree.jpg is in the same folder as this HTML file. I cannot figure out what I could be doing wrong, but I realize that there is probably a simple solution that I am overlooking.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try add relative path for image?

Comment: Hi EagleBeagle... Your code is ok. If the image is in the same folder, verify its name... perhaps its name is all in lower case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after asking a friend who has a little more experience with Flask, I figured out that I needed to make a folder called "static" and a folder within that called "img", and then I made a reference to that folder within my template. (/static/img/Tree.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the image file. "Tree.jpg" may not have a capital T or it could be a .png file instead of a .jpg file. HTML is case sensitive and will not find the image if there is a typo.